# Access to a file location is denied

Tags: file-access, machine.config

Hi, I've installed TFS2010 trial version in my remote machine. While configuring the Application Tier, I am getting an error stated that `TFSJobAgent` did not start. While I was looking into the Error logs, I found this message.

`An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config' is denied. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config) ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config' is denied.`

It looks like access rights. So I changed the the security rights to allow all rights. And I set the access to that location is available to user `Everyone`, but still having the problem. But same software I installed in my laptop and I could able to configure and using it. SO I am waiting for the valuable responses from tech guys to resolve my problem.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 2):

Please check the answer on MSDN here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/b31432bc-5025-45a7-91aa-f96644ce4458. These people had the same problem because in the same session they changed passwords. A reboot should fix it, according to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot to my Almighty. Finally I Configured successfully TFS2010 in my machine. I modified the "Run the TFS Service" in User account instead of system account. Thanks to Real_yggdrasil, the forum which you shared made me to try in that way.